# Can't retrieve the objects from a JSON steam to enumerate

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to get a grasp on how to use block in Objective C. In this simple app I'm writing, I'm getting a set of images as a JSON stream. I'm trying to get the images out and objectify them and then collect them into a `NSMutableArray`. Below is my code

**WebImage.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WebImage : NSObject <NSCopying>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imagePath;

- (id)initWithId:(NSString *)imageId andName:(NSString *)imageName andPath:(NSString *)imagePath;
+ (NSArray *)retrieveAllImages;

@end
```

**WebImage.m**

```
#import "WebImage.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

#define HOST_URL @"http://toonmoodz.osmium.lk/"

@implementation WebImage

#pragma mark - NSCopying
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    WebImage *newImage = [WebImage new];
    newImage.imageId = self.imageId;
    newImage.imageName = self.imageName;
    newImage.imagePath = self.imagePath;

    return newImage;
}

- (id)initWithId:(NSString *)imageId andName:(NSString *)imageName andPath:(NSString *)imagePath
{
    if (self = [self init]) {
        self.imageId = imageId;
        self.imageName = imageName;
        self.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (NSArray *)retrieveAllImages  
{
    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", HOST_URL, @"All_Images.php"] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSDictionary *dict = responseObject[@"Images"];
        NSArray *arr = [dict allValues];
        [arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSDictionary *image = obj;
            NSLog(@"%@", image);
            [images addObject:[[WebImage alloc] initWithId:[image objectForKey:@"id"]
                                                         andName:[image objectForKey:@"name"]
                                                         andPath:[image objectForKey:@"image"]]];
        }];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error in image retrieveing: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];

    return [images copy];
}
```

The incoming JSON stream looks like this

```
{
    Images =  (
        {
            createddate = "2014-01-08 12:20:24";
            id = 1;
            image = "images/Rock_1.png";
            isEnabled = 1;
            name = "Rock_1";
        },
        {
            createddate = "2014-01-08 15:12:26";
            id = 2;
            image = "images/Rock_2.png";
            isEnabled = 1;
            name = "Rock_2";
        }
    );
}
```

My problem is I can't retrieve the image objects from the JSON string. When I debug, the compiler doesn't even go into the GET block in the `retrieveAllImages` method but jumps straight to the return statement.

Can anyone please tell me how to correct this?

I've created a project demonstrating the problem I'm facing and I've uploaded it [here](http://www50.zippyshare.com/v/48293003/file.html) if you wanna take a quick look.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint **inside** the `GET` block? I think the debugger skips over blocks if you approach them from the outside.

Comment: I just tried that but no. It still skips over the block.

Comment: It doesn't enter the failure block either?

Comment: Nope. Just jumps to the return statement at the end.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of right now is your `manager` object may be nil?

Comment: Just checked that too and its not nil. This really is a weird scenario. :/

Comment: This is not a valid json - check for examples [here](http://json.org/example.html)

Comment: The above dump is actually a dump of an NSDictionary representing JSON.  Apparently the OP received the JSON correctly at least once and was able to parse it.

Comment: Thanks - i was mislead by "The incoming JSON stream looks like this"...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is of with

NSDictionary *dict = responseObject[@"Images"];
NSArray *arr = [dict allValues];

responseObject[@"Images"]; returns you a NSArray class. So change you dict to NSArray class. and enumerate with that 'dict' object. You dont need to you arr object.